# Order/sort alphabetical arraryformula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently using Google Sheets to keep track of nominations, which I'm later using for a poll. I'm trying to sort my current arrayformula alphabetically, but I can't seem to make it work - might be because I'm rather new to both Google Sheets and Excel. I've tried to use the **Data > Sort Range by column A, A -> Z**, but it just moves the whole list down (might be because the data is fetched from another sheet). My array looks like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(QUERY(TO_TEXT({Sheet1!A2:A;Sheet1!B2:B;Sheet1!C2:C}))))
```

To sum up: I would like to this the data from the above snippet to be displayed alphabetically A -> Z.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA (sort (UNIQUE (QUERY(TO_TEXT({Sheet1!A2:A;Sheet1!B2:B;Sheet1!C2:C}))),1,true,2,false))
```

It means sort column1 ascending and column2 descending